# How can I connect a existing board to my organisation without copy and paste?

Tags: trello, trello-organization

I cannot find the menu to add a existing board to an organisation. I am the admin of it.

Answer (score 2):

See [**Changing the organization to which a board belongs**](http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/966850-changing-the-organization-to-which-a-board-belongs)

---

On this menu on the right side of the board:

[image: Click "Additional Settings"]

… click "Additional Settings", then click "Change Organization…"

[image: Click "Change Organization"]